# extjs grid restore columns (hide / show) ,width,postion

Tags: extjs, grid

I want to reset the grid columns (hide / show) ,width,postions without reload the page .
I am trying this

```
Ext.getCmp('inventoryResultGrid').applyState(firstState);
```

but it only working for positions.

Comment: did you call grid.getView().refresh()?

Comment: Ext.getCmp('inventoryResultGrid').getView().refresh();   not working for me :(

Answer (score 2):

Try **reconfigure** method  like this.

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('inventoryResultGrid'); 
grid.reconfigure(grid.store, grid.initialConfig.columns);
```

You can find documentation here http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure

Comment: That seems to work it you want to restore column state to initial config values. Still doesn't answer why `applyState` doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Which ExtJS version?

From looking at the sources of GridPanel.applyState() in EXtJS 3.1.4: Applying state after columns are indeed only stores the values in the column model's config, but does not change current settings (except for position).

Something like this should do (untested):

```
function restoreColumnState(grid, state) {
    var cm = grid.getColumnModel(),
        columns = state.columns,
        columnState,
        column,
        columnIndex;
    cm.suspendEvents(true);
    for (var i = 0, len = columns.length; i < len; i++) {
        columnState = columns[i];
        column = cm.getColumnById(columnState.id);
        if (column) {
            columnIndex = cm.getIndexById(columnState.id);
            cm.setHidden(i, columnState.hidden);
            cm.setColumnWidth(i, columnState.width);
            if (columnIndex != i) {
                cm.moveColumn(columnIndex, i);
            }
        }
    }
    cm.resumeEvents();
}
```

Comment: I'm using ExtJS 4 and the grid doesn't have a `getColumnModel` method.